# How to subclass NSNumberFormatter

Tags: swift, macos, interface-builder, nsnumberformatter

I have a macOS app written in Swift with some NSTextFields bind to NSNumbers and with NSNumberFormatters.

Since I need a special formatting for that numbers, I tried to create a custom NSNumberFormatter:

```
class CustomNumberFormatter: NSNumberFormatter {

    override func number(from string: String) -> NSNumber? {
    ....
    }

   override func string(from number: NSNumber) -> String? {
   ....
   }
}
```

Point is that I get this error message:

> 'NSNumberFormatter' has been renamed to 'NumberFormatter'

I try to subclass NumberFormatter but in that case CustomNumberFormatter is not visible in the storyboard.

What do I am missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: just out of curiosity: why would you?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work just fine if I subclass from `NumberFormatter`. Tested putting it into storyboard and it works. Note the Module matches the project "Tester2" so it's picking up the correct class. I'm using Xcode 11.3 (11C29) on macOS 10.15 if that makes a difference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Lucas, thank you for your answer. I am using exactly the same dev environment, but 1) CustomNumberFormatter is not visible in Class, 2) 'Module' is empty and 'Inherit Module From Target' is deselected and disabled. Any idea?

Comment: @Fab I'm not too sure what could be different. Maybe the class isn't part of the same compilation target? If you want to try posting a project on GitHub or something that reproduces the issue I could try it on my end. Sorry, not sure what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I expected to be able to select the CustomNumberFormatter class from the dropdown listbox which is empty instead.

Manually writing the class name solved the issue.

I don't know if this is the expected behavior or not but it worked.